# How to style Inside Javascript/Json Code

Tags: javascript, css, json

I am trying to style a div inside my javascript/json code but not being able to do.Inside my code there is a div named `cart-total` which I am trying to give some style.Below is the part of my code which have `cart-total` div. how can I append some style for `cart-total`

```
if (json['success']) {
    $('#content').parent().before('<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> ' + json['success'] + ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

    // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cart > button').html('<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total'] + '</span>');
    }, 100);

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (i.e. with a working set of code, including HTML and CSS).

Comment: And where you style that element? `.toggleClass`, `.addClass`, `.removeClass`

Comment: If `json['success']` can ever be true, then `json` does not contain JSON. See also http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element created by JS behaves (in most situations) like any other element loaded with the document, so you can just use  `<style>` element with CSS that refers to the class.

You can also use the `style` attribute, if you want.

([More info about CSS](http://w3schools.com/css))

Comment: Thanks actually I put css style to my external css sheet and it was not working.After I put the class directly to my header it starts working.Thanks for your help